# Animating fade-in and fade out for successive lines of text

Tags: css, animation, fadein, fadeout

I am attempting to use the Animate.css library to achieve the following:  Fading the "Simply Reiki" logo together with a string of successive `<p>` elements. Each`<p>` will need to fade in and out, one after the other.

The page in question can be viewed at [Simply Reiki test page](http://www.openconcept.org/simply-reiki/index-01.html)

**OBSERVATIONS**

1. Obviously, "animation-delay" does not function.  Each`<p>` element immediately overlaps the others.
2. It does not seem that "both" will work on the
   fadeIn and perform the fade out.

Here are code snippets for my HTML and CSS:

```css
h1.animated {
  font-size: 5.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Allura', cursive;
  color: #e8e8ea;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: fadeIn forwards 7s 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
p.animated {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Muli', cursive;
  color: #e8e8ea;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: 45px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
p.animated1 {
  animation: fadeIn both 7s;
}
p.animated2 {
  animation-delay: 14s;
  animation: fadeIn both 7s;
}
p.animated3 {
  animation-delay: 21s;
  animation: fadeIn both 7s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-text-wrapper">
  <h1 class="animated">Simply Reiki</h1>
  <p class="animated animated1">Pure · Positive · Powerful</p>
  <p class="animated animated2">Just for today, I will not be angry.</p>
  <br>
  <p class="animated animated3">Just for today, I will not worry.</p>
  <br>
  <p class="animated animated4">Just for today, I will be grateful.</p>
  <br>
  <p class="animated animated5">Just for today, I will do my work honestly.</p>
  <br>
  <p class="animated animated6">Just for today, I will be kind to every living thing.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: three issue mean three question, please edit your question

Comment: Thank you for your reply, waqt.  This is my first question on CS so I apologize if there were concerns relating to the way my question was phrased.  

Ultimately, the question at hand relates to fading successive `<p>` elements in and out.  I have referenced two observations about my code which may be helpful in deducing the answer.  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

use javascript with like this

```
.quotes {display: none;}​
```

```
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
```

```
// code gets installed at the end of the body (after all other HTML)
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
```

See also Working demo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/show/

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  I'm looking forward to giving it a shot later this week.